# Is there a FLV player with fullscreen for Flash 8?

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, flvplayback

I need a player that can play FLV videos in FULLSCREEN inside my Flash8 application.
I know that it can be done using AS3, but I need to use AS2; is there a player that supports fullscreen that can be used?

Answer (score 1):

First page of a Google search has this: http://www.oxylusflash.com/flashfiles/video-player-with-playlist-02-as2-xml.  It's not free, but it shows that they do exist.

Alternatively you could roll your own fairly easily.  Full screen mode works pretty much the same in AS2.  The following toggles the display mode, and could easily be used on a full screen button:

```
Stage.displayState = (Stage.displayState == "normal") ? "fullScreen" : "normal";
```